# Create a PropertyGrid with custom PSObjects in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, propertygrid

I'd like to display the status of several Windows Services into a **[System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.selectedobjects%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)**.

I tried using **SelectedObject** instead of **SelectedObjects** but I cannot figure how to fix the output.

```
$certificate = (Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My\ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).Subject

$hostname = New-Object PSObject 
$hostname | Add-Member Noteproperty sName "Hostname"
$hostname | Add-Member Noteproperty sValue (hostname)
$hostname | Add-Member Noteproperty sReadOnly $True

$cert = New-Object PSObject
$cert | Add-Member Noteproperty sName "Certificate"
$cert | Add-Member Noteproperty sValue ($certificate -imatch $hostname.sValue)

$dot3sv = New-Object PSObject
$dot3sv | Add-Member Noteproperty sName "Dot3svService"
$dot3sv | Add-Member Noteproperty sValue ((Get-Service -Name dot3svc).Status -eq "Running")

$eap = New-Object PSObject
$eap | Add-Member Noteproperty sName "EAPService"
$eap | Add-Member Noteproperty sValue ((Get-Service -Name EapHost).Status -eq "Running")


$PropertyGrid1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid
$PropertyGrid1.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
$PropertyGrid1.SelectedObjects = @($cert, $dot3sv, $eap)
```

This is my current Form output:

```
[+] Default Text I'd like to change
  [0]          |  @{sName="Certificate",sValue=True}
  [1]          |  @{sName="Dot3svService",sValue=True}
  [2]          |  @{sName="EAPService",sValue=True}
```

How can I get the following display?

```
[+] Status
  Certificate     |  True
  Dot3svService   |  True
  EAPService      |  True
```

Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use `Out-GridView` in Powershell V3:

```
$cert,$dot3sv,$eap | Out-GridView
```

Out-GridView is similar to a PropertyGrid but has the advantage that it just works with PowerShell objects (psobject).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! More details on _Out-GridView_ [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730930.aspx)